Using Titan key to initial disk decrypt in Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to configure my Titan key to initial decrypt of hard disk (as an alternative to password).
I'm following the tutorial in Unlocking LUKS2 volumes with TPM2, FIDO2, PKCS#11 Security Hardware on systemd 248
So, I have executed
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1               259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   1,7G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 474,8G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   252:0    0 474,8G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   252:1    0 473,8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 252:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]

Then
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/nvme0n1p3 

And edited /etc/crypttab to add the fido at the disk the option fido2-device=auto
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=83217e6a-4ff0-4d5d-b9eb-xxxxxxxxxxxx none luks,discard,fido2-device=auto

But when I reboot, no change: It continue asking only for password. If I connect the key, it blinks a very few times, but then go down. I guess I have to add some support for USB in initramfs, but I do not know how to do it.
Any suggestion / help?
